# Element.update is not a function [Rails 3 + JQuery]

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ujs

I'm attempting to integrate JQuery into Rails 3.  I've downloaded the rails.js file from http://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs and have included it in my app.  I've also include JQuery.

But when I attempt to do a simple page.replace like so:

```
render :update do |page|
  page.replace_html "my_div", :partial => "my_partial", :locals => {:mylocal => mylocal}
end
```

I get the following error thrown from the javascript executing:

```
RJS error:
TypeError: Element.update is not a function

Element.update("my_div", "mypartialdata");
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 12):

As others have said, `page.replace`, in rails 2, references `Element.update`.

If you want the same helpers available to you in Rails 3 with jQuery, check out jrails:

http://github.com/aaronchi/jrails

In case you want to use the `assert_select_rjs` test helpers in Rails 3, go grab the patched version here:

https://github.com/theworkinggroup/jrails

Answer (score 1):

`page.replace` will call [prototype](http://prototypejs.org/) function `Element.update`. Have you got prototype included in your page?

Answer (score 0):

If it really is just the `Element.update` thing using `render(:update)` in rails 3 with jQuery, this little js code snippet should do it:

```
Element = function(){}
Element.update = function(id,html){$('#'+id).html(html);}
```

parsing this JS code should help.
I've put it at the end of the `jquery_ujs.js` file.

Answer (score -3):

I figured out the problem.  Apparently with JQuery, you cannot use the rails helpers like "replace_html" or "insert_html".  You merely have to do page << "//Jquery code".