# How to make Ajax call to page.replace_html in rails3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery

I have my application recently transferred to rails3.
I have an issue in Ajax call.
In my 'view' page,i used link_to tag like this :--

```
'<%= link_to "#{@album_name.album_name}", { :controller => "admin", :action => "label_album_track", :upc => label.upc, :date => params[:date] }, :remote => true %>'
```

In my controller class, i redirect like this :-

```
 render(:update) { |page|
    page.replace_html 'tab', :partial=>'admin/track' ,:object=>  @track,@dsp_array,@total_track]
}
```

But that's not working. If you have any other rails-ajax tutorial or URL, please reply.

Comment: Do you have the empty div tags? i.e <div id = "tab"></div> ? Also its useful to check the server for any errors when you click on the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer this post it should answer you query
[Element.update is not a function [Rails 3 + JQuery]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3596431/element-update-is-not-a-function-rails-3-jquery)